# Latest 5.63.x is 5.63.4 but is not available for download

Tags: upgrade, security

According to https://civicrm.org/blog/dev-team/civicrm-5650-5644-5634-esr-security-release, a security release was published on 6 Sep 2023 including v5.63.4 but v5.63.4 is not listed at https://download.civicrm.org/release or https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-wordpress/tags

Answer (score 2):

5.63 is the Extended-Security-Release version, which is a subscription service. You can sign up for the ESR service & download that version for a small fee. Read more about it here: https://civicrm.org/blog/kbeireis/esr-long-term-solution

If you do not wish to sign up for extended security releases, you can download the latest version of CiviCRM for free, which contains all security updates.

Comment: Thanks @Coleman
Got it.  Took me a while to get my head around the deeply unconventional CiviCRM release cycle, version numbers and support duration being accustomed to the likes of Ubuntu's LTS and Firefox's ESR.  No complaint.  It is as it is.  Just excusing my lack of understanding.

Comment: You're welcome.